# executable jar from groovy sources

Tags: ant, groovy, executable-jar

I could not find a proper answer to the following question : while creating an executable jar from groovy compiled sources, I cannot simply include `groovy-all-version.jar` in a lib directory (as I would do in java) but I need to extract all the classes from the jar and package them with my own classes as otherwise I get an exception. This actually is the case with all libraries I may want to use.

Not clear ? Let's see an example.

`toto.groovy` belonging to package `titi` is compiled in a `build` directory which looks like this :

```
build
    lib
        groovy-all-1.8.4.jar
    titi
        toto.class
```

and a  `MANIFEST.MF` that will be included in the jar contains the lines:

```
Main-Class: titi.toto
Class-Path: lib/groovy-all-1.8.4.jar
```

Executable jar creation is done with the following `ant` target in `build.xml`:

```
<jar destfile="${build.exe.dir}/${exe.name}" 
    basedir="${build.dir}" 
    manifest="${src.conf.dir}/MANIFEST.MF"
/>
```

Now if I try to execute the jar, I get

```
$ java -jar target/toto.jar 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/Script
```

(I've checked that the `groovy.lang.Script` class exists.)

On the other hand, if I unjar `groovy-all-version.jar` in `build` by adding an `unjar` task before the `jar`, execution goes fine. OK, it works, but it slows down the compilation process and I'd like to understand...

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `target` directory relative to the `lib` and `titi` ones?  If it's a sibling then the Class-Path in the manifest should start `../lib`

Comment: @Robert: build is where source code is compiled. target is where toto.jar go. toto.jar contains what is in build : lib directory which contains groovy-all-version.jar, all class files and the manifest

Comment: I think I see - so you're putting the groovy-all jar file itself inside your main JAR? That won't work as Java can't load classes from a jar-inside-a-jar without help. The manifest Class-Path references other jars at paths relative to the location of this jar, not inside it.

Comment: @Robert: well, this the way I package java programs : all individual jar-ed libs in `lib` directory bundled in the executable `jar` and `Class-Path` clause in manifest lists all of them: `lib/lib1.jar, lib/lib2.jar, ...`.